# JSOUP not getting complete html but working in python urllib2

Tags: jsoup

The website
url=http://m.ibuildapp.com/site/ibuildapp_3/default?filter=webapp&searchText=&searchCat=254&page=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fibuildapp.com%2Fprojects.php%3F#2601
when crawled with java (JSOUP) does't get complete source code(there's no AJAX)
but the python urllib2 gets the whole html easily.
The java code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293 Safari/6531.22.7").timeout(10000).get();
```

only gets half the page's source code where as the python code

```
import urllib2
request = urllib2.Request("http://m.ibuildapp.com/site/ibuildapp_3/default?filter=webapp&searchText=&searchCat=254&page=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fibuildapp.com%2Fproject$
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
request.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_0 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/532.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.5 Mobile/8A293$
filter=webapp&searchText=&searchCat=254&page=1&url=http%3A%2F%2Fibuildapp.com%2Fprojects$
data = opener.open(request).read()
print data
```

What could be wrong?
I have tried adding referrer, cookies and also adding headers.

Comment: Can you provide the results of both, including doc.html();

Comment: Can you please post your solution as an answer and *accept* it? So other's can see it's already solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the header

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
```

fixed the problem